# replace or delete line in txt file

Tags: php, edit, fopen, text-files, fwrite

comm.php

```
<?
$com = $req_user_info['comments'];
$name = $username;

if($_POST) {
$postdate = date("d M y h:i A");
$content = $_POST['commentContent'];
$handle = fopen("$com","a");
fwrite($handle,"<b>" . $name . "</b>:<br>" . $content . "<br>" . $postdate . "<br>"); 
fclose($handle);}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action = "" method = "POST">
Post a Comment<br><textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="commentContent"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Comment"><p>
Comments<p>
<? 
include($com);
?>
</body></html>

/*$req_user_info['comments']; = data.txt*/
```

data.txt

```
Alex: sometext 20 Feb 12 11:11 AM
Alex: sometext 20 Feb 12 11:38 AM
```

What I want to do is delete (or replace with nothing) name, content and postdate.

Example:

Alex: sometext 20 Feb 12 11:11 AM   Delete

Alex: sometext 20 Feb 12 11:38 AM   Delete

So after I click delete and refresh the page I want the line to be gone.

Comment: I'd advise you to use a database instead.

Comment: I'd rather not use a database

Comment: Have you considered potential problems with concurrency?  what happens if two people simultaneously post something?  Your code doesn't seem to handle this case.

Comment: simultaneously posting works fine.

Comment: SQLite gives you the simplicy of a text file and the power of a database in one small file, worth at least a look.

Comment: @user1176495 Unlikely you've tested *actually* simultaneous posting, as in having two instances both with open references to the file. You have a major race condition (race conditions are extremely hard to test for!), since you don't do any locking... Unless you have a VERY good reason ("I'd rather not" isn't!), you should be using a database instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: I find the question requirements to be Unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just including the file normally, you could use fgets to read line by line (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php). Store each line number as you iterate though, then on your delete link, pass the line number.

```
<a href="page.php?delete=XXX">Delete</a>
```

When you then want to delete, simple go through each line and rewrite the file, skipping the line that was given with the delete link variable $_GET['delete']. Just make sure you're counting as you write each new line so you know when to skip a line.

Using the PHP example:

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    $handle = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $counter++;
        echo $buffer . '<a href="page.php?delete='.$counter.'">delete</a>';
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain how to store each line number?

Comment: When you use fgets to loop through each line, simply increment a counter each time you add a line, and then echo the counter's value in place of XXX in my example above.

Comment: I'm sorry can't seem to get it work
`<?
$com = $req_user_info['comments'];
$name = $username;
if($_POST) {
$postdate = date("d M y h:i A");
$content = $_POST['commentContent'];
$handle = fopen("$com","a");
fwrite($handle,"<b>" . $name . "</b>:<br>" . $content . "<br>" . $postdate . "<br>"); 
fclose($handle);}
?>
<form action = "" method = "POST">
Post a Comment<br><textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="commentContent"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Comment"><p>
Comments<p>
<? 
$file = fopen("$com","r");

while(! feof($file))
  {
  echo fgets($file). "<br />";
  }

fclose($file);
?>
`

Comment: I have edited my text above to show how to add a counter and 'store' the line numbers

Comment: I find it very inadvisable to create a script that deletes which is based on a `$_GET` request.  This would be very easy for someone (or something) to systematically destroy all of your data.